# How to add pygtk package in yocto

Tags: python, debian, package, gtk, yocto

I am using the latest master branch of poky and meta-oe. I need pygtk package for one of my application as it is one of the requirements for it to run.

I searched http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=pygtk  and it listed two of the recipes and I believe the WiFiRadar depends on pygtk and is not providing it .

Another one is meta-debian.. Now I am confused, as they are still in morty branch.. Do I have to include meta-debian for adding pygtk package. Is there any way of getting only pygtk instead of adding the whole meta-debian layer which is complex.

Comment: In [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#migration-2.1-removed-recipes) it says python-pygtk is obsolete.

Comment: Then what should I do for it to use..Switch back to 2.0 version

Comment: I don't know what WifiRadar is for but there are no alternatives? Otherwise, you can copy [jethro recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-pygtk_2.24.0.bb?h=jethro) into your layer and adapt it to work on rocko. Or, you can also port wifi-radar to up-to-date GTK3.

Comment: Noted. Will try porting jethro recpie into  rocko..